# How to establish a sftp connection without the use of Java Secured Channel

Tags: java, jsp

This code is written using JSch. i am need of the code to establish sftp connection without using JSch.

Also the code should work in java 1.4.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.*;

public class FileUploadSftp    {
    public static void main(String args[]) {            
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        String sServer = "resident.com";
        int SFTPPORT = 22;
        String sUserId = "xyz";
        String sPassword = "abc";
        JSch jsch = new JSch();    
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(sUserId, sServer,SFTPPORT);
            session.setPassword(sPassword);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want sftp then find a ftp client - I think apache does one

Comment: Thank you for your response...Only Sftp is enabled...

Comment: so what do you mean *without secured channel* ?

Comment: Whether it is possible using SCP without using JSch???? With the above code am getting the exception.... java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-256 MessageDigest not available 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-384 MessageDigest not available 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-512 MessageDigest not available 
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException